# "Permission denied" on file when running a docker container

Tags: dockerfile, chmod, docker-image, docker-run

I have a file that I can't edit but needs to run on in a docker container. Because the file doesn't have an extension, I have to use chmod for setting the file executable. But after I build the docker image from the docker file I always get a `"permission denied" error`

My docker file:

```
FROM alpine

COPY . /home/guestuser/bin/gateway

RUN apk add libressl-dev
RUN apk add libffi-dev

RUN pwd

WORKDIR /home/guestuser/bin/.
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "gateway"]

RUN pwd

CMD ["/home/guestuser/bin/gateway"]


EXPOSE 11878
```

I alwas get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/home/guestuser/bin/gateway\": permission denied": unknown.
```

As I already mentioned, I am not able to edit the file I want to execute. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this simple one.

```
FROM alpine
COPY . /home/guestuser/bin/gateway
RUN apk add libressl-dev
RUN apk add libffi-dev
WORKDIR /home/guestuser/bin/
RUN chmod -R 755 /home/guestuser
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/home/guestuser/bin/gateway"]
```

Otherwise, run sleep command login to container and see your commands works manually

Comment: I already tried the step with `"/bin/bash"`. And with your suggestion the error: `: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.` appears.

Comment: i gave is sample. Make sure the path is correct. Check using which command. which bash or which sh

Comment: How do you get "bash" to run? Bash is not in alpine and after I added it manually , I had the problem that "bash" `cannot execute binay file `

Comment: As the OP noted, bash doesn't come with Alpine, so this example in its current form will never run. Please revise it.

Answer (score 0):

### It looks like you are using the exec form of CMD, as shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

There are two ways to use CMD. The first is the way you are already doing it, in exec form:

```
CMD ["/home/guestuser/bin/gateway"]
```

Or you could use shell form:

```
CMD /home/guestuser/bin/gateway
```

If you need a shell you could also explicitly call one in exec form, which is what Ganesh was trying to suggest.

```
CMD ["sh", "/home/guestuser/bin/gateway"]
```

### But if that syntax is correct, why didn't it work?

Well, because this is assuming that `gateway` is a *file*. The issue is... it probably isn't.

When you run this command:

```
COPY . /home/guestuser/bin/gateway
```

From the reference:

> Multiple  resources may be specified but the paths of files and directories will be interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build.

You are copying the *entire contents of the build context* into the **directory** `/home/guestuser/bin/gateway`. If you want to copy a specific file, you should name it explicitly rather than using `.` The COPY command's syntax is source first, then destination, as shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

So when you are trying to execute gateway, you are probably "executing" a *directory* named gateway. So long as there is more than one file in the build context, gateway will be a directory. That can include the Dockerfile itself, so even if the build context is a folder with just the Dockerfile and the script you want to run, you'll still pull in both files, which turns gateway itself into a directory.

### Tests you can try

As proof that your Dockerfile CMD syntax is correct, try changing that CMD to something like this:

```
CMD ["top"]
```

Similarly, you can remove the CMD and just run the container in interactive mode. It will drop you in your WORKDIR, which is empty except for the gateway **directory**, complete with the contents of whatever directory structure was pulled in during the build process.

So, to make this work, change your COPY line to name the script you want:

```
COPY somescript /home/guestuser/bin/gateway
```

Other notes:

- your default user here is root, so you don't need to chmod gateway
- `RUN pwd` will only show the first time you build the container